# How can I find out what my Apollo Graph Ref is?

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

You have specified an Apollo key but have not specified a graph ref; usage reporting is disabled. To enable usage reporting, set the `APOLLO_GRAPH_REF` environment variable to `your-graph-id@your-graph-variant`. To disable this warning, install `ApolloServerPluginUsageReportingDisabled`

I am struggling to find instructions for how to 'finish' the setup for an apollo classic graph. All of this worked fine last week but no longer does (I can see on Apollo's instructions page that something changed on 4 Oct and maybe requires people to change their graph reference).

I'm trying to solve these problems one step at a time, but cannot make sense of the instructions for apollo.

The format represented in the error message has two fragments, separated by an 'a' symbol. The format of the apollo key in the federation 2 instructions also has two fragments, but they are separated by a colon.

Answer (score 0):

To find `your-graph-id@your-graph-variant`, log in to the apollo sutdio, got to `settings` and under the `This Graph` tab, look at the first section of `General` settings, you should find `your-graph-id`.

The `variant` is usually defaulted as `current`, i.e `variant=current`. If you have specified a different variant, be sure to use it.

In your `.env` you'd have to specify these two keys:

```
APOLLO_KEY=<your-apollo-api-key>
APOLLO_GRAPH_REF=<your-graph-id>@<current-or-your-variant>
```

Restart your server and you should be good.